Using Pandas 2.0 with Python 3.8 without Zoneinfo
I am running some code using Python 3.8. As it is for a scientific experiment that has already been run in this configuration before, I cannot currently update to a newer version of Python. I am using pandas, which needs zoneinfo, which is only part of Python 3.9 and up. I know that it should be possible to somehow still use pandas 2.0.2, because I have the code installed somewhere else, where the missing zoneinfo doesn't cause any problems. I just don't know how. Can anyone help me get pandas to work?
I have tried installing backports but obviously then I would need to redirect pandas to use backports instead of zoneinfo, and I don't know how I can do that in an easy way.

The answer was making sure pytz was up to date!

Either you choose the approach suggested in this answer: ERROR: Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
or you try (as I do, for the same reasons you explained:
import sys

if sys.version_info.major == 3 and sys.version_info.minor < 9:
    from backports import zoneinfo
else:
    from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo



I feel like a total noob but where should I add this? Since it is not an important statement in my own code, but the import statements in pandas? As far as I can see there are several import statements for zoneinfo in the whole pandas package, should I change all of them?

Add it in the import section of the code

You mean of my own code?

Either that or the one where the dependency exists
